# The expansion of the product of the sum of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Guys,

I want to expand the product of the sum of polynomials into the form of  $\sum\limits_{}^{} {a{x^b}} $,

$\begin{array}{l}
I = \left( {\frac{{\lambda _1^0}}{{0!}}{x^0} + \frac{{\lambda _1^1}}{{1!}}{x^1} + \frac{{\lambda _1^2}}{{2!}}{x^2} +  \cdots \frac{{\lambda _1^N}}{{N!}}{x^N}} \right) \cdot \left( {\frac{{\lambda _2^0}}{{0!}}{x^0} + \frac{{\lambda _2^1}}{{1!}}{x^1} + \frac{{\lambda _2^2}}{{2!}}{x^2} +  \cdots \frac{{\lambda _2^N}}{{N!}}{x^N}} \right)\\
 \cdot \left( {\frac{{\lambda _3^0}}{{0!}}{x^0} + \frac{{\lambda _3^1}}{{1!}}{x^1} + \frac{{\lambda _3^2}}{{2!}}{x^2} +  \cdots \frac{{\lambda _3^N}}{{N!}}{x^N}} \right) \cdots \left( {\frac{{\lambda _M^0}}{{0!}}{x^0} + \frac{{\lambda _M^1}}{{1!}}{x^1} + \frac{{\lambda _M^2}}{{2!}}{x^2} +  \cdots \frac{{\lambda _M^N}}{{N!}}{x^N}} \right)
\end{array}$

Thanks so much and your help will be appricated!

Comment: So we have $M$ sequences $S=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_N)$ where $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_N).(b_0,a_1,\dots,b_N)=(c_0,c_1,\dots,c_{2N})$ with $c_i=\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}b_j$. Conjecture a result for the $i$th term of $S^m$ by computing for $m=2,3$ and use induction.

Comment: Dear Shahab, Thanks so much for your kind help!